# Read all csv files quickly and update shared dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, counter

I'm new to python and pandas but here's what I want to do.
I want to read through all the csv files in a directory and retrieve one cell of data from the file and update a count on a dictionary, with the retrieve value being a key in the dictionary. I have to do this for ~6000 csv files. How can I do this quickly?

```
stats = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0, 'D':0}
for file in f:
    df = pandas.read_csv(file)
    type = df["type"].head(1)[0]
    stats[type]+=1
```

The order in which I read the files don't matter. I was hoping to do this concurrently, sharing the dictionary. Unless there is a better approach to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Could you share an example of how the csv files look? Which cell are you interested in reading? Is it in the first few rows? How does the dictionary look, are you only interested in updating one key-value pair?

Comment: @jpp i've posted what i've done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize your logic significantly by:

- Reading only the first row.
- Reading only the required column.
- Creating a lazy iterable from the first value of the desired column.
- Feeding the resulting iterable to `collections.Counter`.

Here's some code which should help:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

res = Counter(pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1, columns=['type'])['type'].iloc[0] \
              for file in f)
```

The beauty of `Counter` is there's no need to specify keys in advance. Also note `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so you are not relinquishing any functionality.